# How to access RSVP in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

RSVP is packaged as a module in Ember.js. However, it doesn't seem to be globally available. I would like to use `RSVP.all` for resolving a nondeterministic number of promises. Is there another way to access this functionality or perhaps require the module elsewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access to RSVP was just added to the `Ember` namespace in this commit: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/d433d59690eac9a368432e01324d6424a3480d95

Comment: Yeah, I notified Stefan that it was missing and he added it :) Looks like it was an oversight

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with modules, but the only place they are used is in the DeferredMixin (see [source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/deferred.js)). So it is not publicly available.

Have you tried to require it yet?

```
var RSVP = requireModule("rsvp");
```